# How do I use mysql variables with php mysql extension?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm doing this query from any mysql client, and it's working:

```
SELECT
  q.calldate,
  q.dst,
  @ts_dnd_activate   := IF(q.dst='*78',q.calldate,@ts_dnd_activate) AS dndact,
  @ts_dnd_deactivate := IF(q.dst='*79',q.calldate,NULL) AS dnddeact,
  TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,@ts_dnd_activate,@ts_dnd_deactivate) AS tdiff
FROM
  (SELECT calldate,dst
   FROM cdr
   WHERE calldate>='2012-01-09 11:12:08' AND src=1004 AND dst IN ('*78','*79')
   ORDER BY calldate DESC) q
```

It gets two fields from a table and, based on the value of the dst field, uses mysql variables to calculate the difference between the calldates fields, which is a timestamp.

If I run this query in PHP code:

```
[...]
$q = "SELECT
        q.calldate,
        q.dst,
        @ts_dnd_activate   := IF(q.dst='*78',q.calldate,@ts_dnd_activate) AS dndact,
        @ts_dnd_deactivate := IF(q.dst='*79',q.calldate,NULL) AS dnddeact,
        TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,@ts_dnd_activate,@ts_dnd_deactivate) AS tdiff
      FROM
       (SELECT calldate,dst
        FROM cdr
        WHERE calldate>='2012-01-09 11:12:08' AND src=1004 AND dst IN ('*78','*79')
        ORDER BY calldate DESC) q";
$rs = mysql_query($q,$database);
[...]
```

I'll never get the tdiff field, because I'm getting rows where the mysql variables are always NULL, like this:

```
Array
(
    [calldate] => 2012-01-09 12:20:10
    [dst] => *78
    [dndact] => 2012-01-09 12:20:10
    [dnddeact] => 
    [tdiff] => 
)
Array
(
    [calldate] => 2012-01-09 12:22:05
    [dst] => *79
    [dndact] => 
    [dnddeact] => 2012-01-09 12:22:05
    [tdiff] => 
)
Array
(
    [calldate] => 2012-01-09 12:25:15
    [dst] => *78
    [dndact] => 2012-01-09 12:25:15
    [dnddeact] => 
    [tdiff] => 
)
Array
(
    [calldate] => 2012-01-09 12:29:21
    [dst] => *79
    [dndact] => 
    [dnddeact] => 2012-01-09 12:29:21
    [tdiff] => 
)
```

Please note that it is a SINGLE query, but it seems that it's impossible to use mysql variables with the php mysql base extension because I don't know why but it seems to set to null every row.

What I'm doing wrong? Is it a new problem?

P.S. please don't tell me I've to use PDO or mysqli; its an old project that I can't rewrite.

Comment: Am I missing something here? Wouldn't tdiff be null if it couldn't calculate the timestamp? In every example you've posted, either dndact or dnddeact is missing.

Comment: calldate has always a value. In the query you can see 2 if:
IF(q.dst='*78',q.calldate,@ts_dnd_activate) 
IF(q.dst='*79',q.calldate,NULL) 
so: 
on the 1st row calldate="2012-01-09 12:20:10" and dst="*78", so ts_dnd_activate (dndact) become "2012-01-09 12:20:10",
on the 2nd row calldate="2012-01-09 12:22:05" and dst="*79", so ts_dnd_deactivate (dnddeact) become "2012-01-09 12:22:05". 
var ts_dnd_activate was NEVER reset to null so the the diff must have some value. 
If I run this query from the MySQL CLI interface it works perfectly, but in PHP I'll get the result you can see in my example.

Comment: This may be of help to you (from the [doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html)): As a general rule, you should never assign a value to a user variable and read the value within the same statement. You might get the results you expect, but this **is not guaranteed**. The order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined and may change based on the elements contained within a given statement; in addition, this order is not guaranteed to be the same between releases of the MySQL Server.

Comment: Chris, you're right. I think it's the problem, I must change the way I do the query. Anyway it sound strange to me that the same query was executed in different way from php.